# Google Drive upload in Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api, service-accounts

We have a requirement where we should provide capability to upload files up to 100 GB size. Current flow which we have is to put the file from client location/local system to the application server. Then application server pushes the file to a service account in Google Drive server. I would like to know if there is a way to push the file from local system directly to service account in Google Drive. This would help us to not have to store such big files in application server. Anyone has any suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are not meant to be used like this. They have limited quota: [Google Drive Service Accounts Additional Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434186/google-drive-service-accounts-additional-storage)